# Visual Studio 2010 Professional and Team Foundation Server 2012 Express

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I can't create a New Team Project from Team Explorer in VS 2010 Profesional because of the below error message:

[image]

> TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without required permissions or with an older version of Team Explorer. Contact your project administrator to check your permissions or to determine how to upgrade Team Explorer.

I'm an administrator in TFS and part of the "Team Foundation Adminstrators" group. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Also, I've installed SP1 for VS2010 and the [KB2662296](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) Hotfix.

Comment: Have you tried creating a project with Team Explorer 2012?  That certainly seems to be what the dialog is indicating to you.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Can I use Team Explorer 2012 with VS 2010?

Comment: No, it is a separate installation.  If you install it, it will install Team Explorer 2012 standalone, side-by-side from your VS 2010 instance.  After that, you can use VS 2010 with the GDR patch - you will need the updated Team Explorer only to create Team Projects.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. How can I give you credit for the answer if it works?

Comment: Let me write up an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error message is indicating that Team Explorer 2012 is required to create a Team Project against Team Foundation Server 2012.

You should install Team Explorer 2012 in order to create your Team Project.  If you do not have Visual Studio 2012 installed, Team Explorer 2012 will install as a standalone application that you can use to connect to TFS.  This will be installed side-by-side with Visual Studio 2010, it will not upgrade your existing installation.  As Allen notes in his answer, you can connect to a TFS 2012 instance from Visual Studio 2010.  You need a matching Team Explorer version **only** to create a Team Project.

Comment: Thanks both of you for helping me out.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need VS2010 SP1, and the forward compatibility upgrade GDR patch to enable VS2010 to connect to TFS2012. However, the Team Explorer shipped with VS2010 and all its variants (beta, RTM, SP1) do not support creating a Team Project by design.

See Buck Hodges post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/03/05/permission-error-with-creating-a-team-project-from-vs-2010-on-tfs-11-beta.aspx.

Buck asserts you will need Team Explorer 2012 just to create the Team Project, **but afterwards it is safe to use Team Explorer 2010 for all other purposes**. That's an important point.

- The VS2010 SP1 Link is
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691
- The GDR Link is
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082
- The Team Explorer 2012 Link is 
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656
  (note this will install the VS2012
  shell as mentioned by [Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson) )

I've confirmed that with this setup you can create a Team Project with Team Explorer via the VS2012 shell and then connect to it afterwards in VS2010 Team Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Install [VS2010SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2182621) first and then the [compat gdr patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) to connect to TFS2012.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've already done both of those. I thought it showed up after the "Also" in my question, but it didn't so I'll update the question. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm on update1...Here was the name of the download file "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2012 with Update 1 - English" from http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-team-foundation-server-express.

Comment: i still feel the gdr patch is not installed properly

Comment: Ok. I will uninstall it and try again. I tried to install it once and it failed, then the second time it worked.